# I try to print all the items the customer has in his shopping cart. But a weird error suddenly popped up

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, iterator, set

this is the Item class

```
class Item
{
private:
    string _name;
    string _serialNumber;
    int _count;
    double _unitPrice;

public:

//C'tor & D'tor
Item(string name, string serialNumber, double unitPrice);
~Item();

double totalPrice() const;

//getters
string getName() const;
string getSerial() const;
double getPrice() const;
int getCount() const;

//setters
void setCount(int newCount);

//operators
bool operator <(const Item& other) const;
bool operator >(const Item& other) const;
bool operator ==(const Item& other) const;

Item& operator ++();
Item operator ++(int);

Item& operator --();
Item operator--(int);
};
```

and the Customer class:

```
class Customer
{
private:
    string _name;
    std::set<Item> _items;

public:

    Customer(string name);
    Customer();
    ~Customer();

    double totalSum();

    std::set<Item> getItems() const;
    string getName() const;

    void addItem(Item item);
    void removeItem(Item item);
};
```

The customer is entered into a map with a key that is his name.

```
std::map<string, Customer> abcCustomers;
```

In the main func, I want to print all the objects using a loop like this:

```
cout << "These are your items: " << endl;

        std::set<Item>::iterator it;
        for (it = abcCustomers[name].getItems().begin(); it != abcCustomers[name].getItems().end(); it++)
        {
            //cout << it.getName() << endl;
        }
```

But for some reason, a red line pops up below the "=" and "!=" Operators with the following error message:

no operator = matches these operands

Can anyone help me with this? thank you very much.

Comment: There should be more to the error message than that. Typically it'll tell you what types are being used in the assignment, and that bit of information solves they mystery.

Comment: `std::set<Item> getItems() const;` returns a copy of the container, not a reference, So the begin and end iterators don't point to the same container.

Comment: Off-topic: `~Item();` -- `~Customer()` -- These destructors are not necessary.  Either declare them as `= default;` or remove them completely.  Even if you're using them to simply write out a message to the screen, remove the message in the final build and the destructors.  Writing empty, do-nothing destructors changes the traits of the class, and can potentially cause the compiler to create non-optimal code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the reported error with the given code and my attempt to hack out [a simple, complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/W77M3b16z) seems to have solved the problem. Every change we need to make to the code to reproduce your problem is a opportunity to insert a new mistake and give you a wrong answer solving it or accidentally fix the mistake. You're better off making and providing a [mre], assuming making the MRE didn't end early with you spotting and fixing the problem.

Comment: Yes, if you solved the "error" you are claiming, you would have hit another error, and it is the one @RetiredNinja pointed out.